# why "Catch-Control" not works?

Tags: http

I make a placeholder service, I add a "cache-control" header by nginx:

[image]

But when I visit this url ( https://z.wiki/placeholder/300x400 ) by chrome, there is not cache, why ? thx~

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), not `cache-control`

Comment: @Alexander I tried, not works.

Comment: Developer tools typically turn the cache off.

Comment: @Alexander HTTP headers are not case-sensitive.

Comment: @Evert Huh, TIL.